# For each inserted row create row in other table with foreign key constrain

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have 2 tables with foreign key constraint:

```
Table A:
[id] int identity(1, 1) PK,
[b_id] INT
```

and

```
Table B:
[id] int identity(1, 1) PK
```

where [b_id] refers to [id] column of Table B.

The task is:
On each insert into table A, and new record into table B and update [b_id].

Sql Server 2008 r2 is used.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what about creating a trigger? which will add record to B?

Comment: i have no idea how this trigger should look like

Comment: Do you have any other data in Table B or just an ID field?

Comment: The answer will depend on the other columns in B and whether they allow nulls or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having misread this the first time, I am posting a totally different answer.

First if table B is the parent table, you insert into it first. Then you grab the id value and insert into table A.

It is best to do this is one transaction. Depending on what the other fields are, you can populate table A with a trigger from table B or you might need to write straight SQL code or a stored procedure to do the work.

It would be easier to describe what to do if you have a table schema for both tables. However, assuming table B only has one column and table A only has ID and B_id, this is the way the code could work (you would want to add explicit transactions for production code). The example is for a single record insert which would not happen from a trigger. Triggers should always handle multiple record inserts and it would have to be written differently then. But without knowing what the columns in the tables are it is hard to provide a good example of this.

```
create table #temp (id int identity)
create table #temp2 (Id int identity, b_id int)
declare @b_id int
insert into #temp default values
select @B_id = scope_identity()
insert into #temp2 (B_id)
values(@B_id)

select * from #temp2
```

Now the problem gets more complex if there are other columns, as you would have to provide values for them as well.

Answer (score 0):

Without removing identity specification you can use the following option:
**SET IDENTITY_INSERT B ON**

Try this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterInsert ON [dbo].[A] 
FOR INSERT
AS 



IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 RETURN;
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SET IDENTITY_INSERT B ON

DECLARE @B_Id INT 
SELECT @B_Id = ISNULL(MAX(Id), 0) FROM B;

WITH RES (ID, BIDS)
AS
(SELECT Id, @B_Id + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) FROM INSERTED)
UPDATE A SET [b_Id] = BIDS
FROM A 
    INNER JOIN RES ON A.ID = RES.ID 

INSERT INTO B (Id) 
SELECT @B_Id + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Id) FROM INSERTED

SET IDENTITY_INSERT B OFF
```

GO

Comment: This is overly complex, there is no need at all to turn of the identity insert and it does not address the problem of other fields in tableB.

Comment: @HLGEM Do you see the other fields in the tableB ?

Comment: @HLGEM Any of your three triggers does not address the problem of main idea of this task.
Firstly - any of your three triggers does not work with multiple inserts.
Secondly - were did you see the [b_Id] column in the Table B ?
Third -  Did you try insert identity column without applying the DENTITY_INSERT option?

Comment: All of my triggers handle multiple records. You are right though that I missed that b_id was in table A. Normally you don't insert the FK  and then the identity. I have removed my downvote.  If there is a PK/fk here then he could have a real problem with what he is trying to do because it won't let him put a value in table a without the value for table b. If table b will be populated by table A, then the ID column should not be an indentity. If it is ometimes populated elsewhere, and also poulated from A, then you are likely to run into a problem iof uniqueness of the value. Bad table design.

Comment: I assume there are other fields in B, the OP didn't say. But there is no reason to have tableB when the data is Table A unless there are other fields.

Comment: Yes, completely agree that there is no reason for such kind of tables design.

Answer (score -1):

Though Nadeem's answer is on the right track, his trigger for some reason takes max.id instead of NEW.id and doesn't update A accordingly.

For what you ask to be usable by trigger, you need the FK in table A to be nulleable, else you have a race condition between the tables.

EDIT: As SpectralGhost pointed out, my original code didn't support multiple rows, this one will do:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trgAfterInsertA ON TableA
FOR INSERT
AS  

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT id FROM INSERTED

DECLARE @an_id int

OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @an_id   
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

INSERT INTO TableB VALUES(VALUE_PLACEHOLDER)

UPDATE TableA
SET b_id = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
WHERE id = @an_id

FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @an_id  
END

GO
```

The VALUE_PLACEHOLDER are the values you initialize TableB with.

Comment: You're trigger won't work for multiple inserted records.

Comment: @SpectralGhost You are right, edited my answer with a CURSOR to consider such case.

Comment: There is no circumstance wehre you should ever use a cursor in a trigger.